# How to create an observable from a plain array?

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

This is my current setup:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public FullBuildModel FullBuild { get; } = new FullBuildModel();
    public ICommand RecalculateSolverCommand { get; }
}

public class FullBuildModel : ReactiveObject
{
    PlayerClass @class;
    public PlayerClass Class { get => @class; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref @class, value); }

    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<PlayerMasterySkillWithCountModel[]> skillsWithCount;
    public PlayerMasterySkillWithCountModel[] SkillsWithCount => skillsWithCount.Value;
}

public class PlayerMasterySkillWithCountModel : ReactiveObject
{
    int allocated;
    public int Allocated { get => allocated; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref allocated, value); }
}

public class PlayerSkill
{
}
```

My binding code is like this:

```
        this.WhenActivated(dc =>
        {
            ViewModel.FullBuild.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SkillsWithCount)
                .Subscribe(skillsWithCount => skillsWithCount
                    .Select(w => w.ObservableForProperty(m => m.Allocated).Select(_=>System.Reactive.Unit.Default)).Amb()
                    .InvokeCommand(ViewModel.RecalculateSolverCommand)
                    .DisposeWith(dc))
                .DisposeWith(dc);
        });
```

The idea is that whenever a skill's allocated count changes, I want to run the recalculate command. `Amb()` got me close, but it only triggers on the first change for some reason. I also tried `CombineLatest()` as per the official documentation, but that triggered on nothing.

How do I merge the enumerable of observables into one observable I can use to invoke a command? I don't care which triggered, I just care that *one* of them triggered. I guess I could loop over the array and individually run a `WhenAnyValue` on every item and map it to my command, but I'm so close that there *has* to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to flatten out the array, subscribe to each item, and merge the results into a single stream. The nested Select helps takes care of that part. `AllocatedStream` referenced in the snippet below is an `IObservable<int>` property created from `WhenAnyValue` of the Allocated property. After merging the children into a single stream,  Switch makes sure all of those child subscriptions are disposed of before subscribing to the new elements (when SkillsWithCount gets reassigned).

```
ViewModel.FullBuild.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SkillsWithCount)
    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.AllocatedStream).Merge())
    .Switch()
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default) 
    .InvokeCommand(ViewModel.RecalculateSolverCommand)
    .DisposeWith(dc);
```

This assumes that you're not mutating the array (e.g. SkillsWithCount[i] = someOtherObject) because then you'd have to handle unsubscribing from the old element on your own.

Comment: I’m not mutating it, only recreating it completely (hence the first WhenAnyValue). Thank you, I’ll try this!